# keep dot separated file grunt-babel

Tags: gruntjs, babeljs

I am using [grunt-babel](https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel) to transform ES6 to ES5. One of my filename is app.collection.js, after running the task, its renaming file to app.js .

What is the [babel option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) to fix this issue.

```js
/****************************************************************************
 * Grunt Babel Compile ES6 to ES5
 ****************************************************************************/
babel: {
  options: {
    blacklist: ['strict'],
    comments: true,
    loose: ["es6.classes", "es6.properties.computed"],
    "ignore": [
    ]
  },
  dist: {
    files: [{ // Dictionary of files
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.path.app.js %>',
      src: ['**/**/*.js'],
      dest: '<%= config.path.app.js %>',
      ext: '.js'
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: would help if you shared the relevant code

Comment: @sfletche updated the questions. Please check if you can help !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either remove the `ext` property altogether or add `extDot` property with value last to keep the `app.collection.js` name.

```
files: [{ // Dictionary of files
  expand: true,
  cwd: '<%= config.path.app.js %>',
  src: ['**/**/*.js'],
  dest: '<%= config.path.app.js %>',
  ext: '.js',
  extDot: 'last'
}]
```

See more at [Building the files object dynamically @ gruntjs.com](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)

> `extDot` Used to indicate where the period indicating the extension is located. Can take either 'first' (extension begins after the first period in the file name) or 'last' (extension begins after the last period), and is set by default to 'first' [Added in 0.4.3]